# When I called spring data JPA paged query, thrown 'PageImpl: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-data-jpa

I want to use spring cache,and added it on findAll(Pageable pageable),as bellow:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"familyUserDao"})
public interface FamilyUserDao extends JpaRepository<FamilyUser,Long> {
    @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "methodName +#p0")
    Page<FamilyUser> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I called
    Page familyUserPage = familyUserDao.findAll(pageable);
the first time,it works,but when I called the second time, it thrown as bellow:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not         read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl: no suitable constructor found, can  not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@7fae8571; line: 1, column: 46]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@7fae8571; line: 1, column: 46]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:73)
```

In fact it's a deserialize issue, the Page's default implement class is PageImpl. But it has no default constructor,  So how to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Cacheable method with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415658/spring-cacheable-method-with-pagination)

Answer (score 1):

when you call the method you have to pass in parametre, two attributes of type Page and integer like continuation:

```
Page familyUserPage = familyUserDao.findAll (int page, int size);
```

to display the first 10 objects, you put the page at 0 and the size at 10, for 10 following the page at 1 and the size at 10 ...